# How to restrict user to edit only one field after record is closed?

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule

I want to create a validation rule where sales manager profile can only change the picklist field stage of the closed opportunity and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is when the object is closed, change the record type to 'Closed' and then create a new page layout that only has the picklist field as editable and all other fields as read only

Assign the sales mgr profile | record type=Closed combination to that restricted-edit page layout

No validation rule required

Answer (score 0):

There is a `IsChanged` formula which checks if a field is changed during that transactions. You could create a validation rule which checks for every field but that approach may not be optimal (1) such formula would be too lengthy and prone to errors 2) needs maintenance as you will have to update formula each time you add/remove a field).

I would think writing a before update trigger which checks for field updates with old and new opty and throw error. You could use [Salesforce Describe](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) capability to dynamically query the fields and use that to compare.

Here is a draft implementation of such utility method. You can check if list contains any fields other than your allowed, you can throw error.

```
public List<String> getChangedFields(SObject s1, SObject s2)  {

    Schema.SObjectType sobj = s1.getSObjectType();
    List<String> updatedFields = new List<String>();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = sobj.getDescribe().Fields.getMap();
    for (String fieldName : fields.keySet()) {

        //Strings when compared with == ignores the case so 
        //we will compare them explicitly
        if (s1.get(fieldName) instanceof String) {
            if (!((String) s1.get(fieldName)).equals((String) s2.get(fieldName))) {
                updatedFields.add(fieldName);
            }
        } else if (s1.get(fieldName) != s2.get(fieldName)) {
            updatedFields.add(fieldName);
        }
    }

    return updatedFields;
}
```

Comment: if opportunity is closed and sales manager only be able to change the stage and nothing else for closed opportunity. how it will be possible?

Comment: With in the trigger you can check for currently logging user's profile. If profile is Sales Manager, and if Opty Status is Closed and If changed fields include only stage name, then allow, else throw error.